# Show that every zero is simple

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G\in\mathbb{C}$ domain, and $f\in Hol\left(\overline{G}\right)$ Let $\left\{ z_{j}\right\}$ be the zeroes of f in $G$. Moreover, $f(z)\neq0$ for every $z\in\partial G$. show that: $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\intop_{\partial G}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\sum z_{j} $$

the residue of $z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ at $z_j$ is $m_j \cdot z_j$ when $m_j$ is the order of $z_j$. I need to show that $m_j = 1$ and the claim will be derived by residue theorem

Comment: There's nothing in the statement that allows to deduce that all zeros are simple. The sum needs to be understood as listing each zero according to multiplicity (each zero is listed as often as its multiplicity says in the sequence(?) $\{z_j\}$, presumably).

Comment: Is it stated clearly that $z_j$ are distinct ? Maybe $z_j$ are repeated with multiplicity, because in general, there is no reason such a $f$ would have simple zeros

Comment: The question was stated exactly like that.. But probably the sum is considered with multiplicities, I didn't think it's true either. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)=(z-a)^mg(z)$, with $g(a)\neq0$ then $f'(z)=(z-a)^{m-1}[mg(z)+(z-a)g'(z)]$. Therefore $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{mg(z)+(z-a)g'(z)}{(z-a)g(z)}.$$

Notice the numerator doesn't vanish at $z=a$, ($mg(a)+(a-a)g'(a)=mg(a)\neq0$), and the denominator vanishes at $z=a$ but only to order one.